# TF lite - ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 11 but expected 1 for dimension 2 of input 0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I implemented several different tutorials on how to utilize a quantized model on tensorflow lite. The relevant part of the code is:

```
    # Load the quantized model
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='quantized_model.tflite')
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

    input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
    input_tensor= np.array(audio_windowed, dtype=np.float32)

    input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, input_tensor)

    #Run the inference
    interpreter.invoke()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
```

where `audio_windowed` has shape `(11, 43844, 1)`.
However, I get the following error

```
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 11 but expected 1 for dimension 2 of input 0.
```

which occurs at line `interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, input_tensor)`

For debugging purposes:

```
print(input_tensor.shape,input_index, input_shape)
```

returns

```
(1, 43844, 11) 0 [    1 43844     1]
```